# External xilinx PCie driver with Yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, fpga, yocto, xilinx

I compiled the xilinx pcie driver using this as a starting point.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules
and then instead of using this to the prebuilt image:
MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "kernel-module-mymodule"
I copy kernel file .ko directly to the image as:
fs@fs:/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_imx7/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/met/0.1-r0$ scp xpcie.ko root@172.17.100.101:/lib/modules
then when I insert this kernel module with hardware connected:
root@imx7d-phyboard-zeta-001:/lib/modules# insmod /lib/modules/xpcie.ko

```
Base hw val 0

Base hw len 0

BAR0 of 0K

BAR0 of 0M

xpcie: Init: Could not remap memory.

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/xpcie.ko: Operation       
not permitted
```

root@imx7d-phyboard-zeta-001:/lib/modules#

What is the reason?
Is it not allowed to copy kernel directly on already built image like this?
Futhermore when I add it to the image as in local.conf file:

```
MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "kernel-module-mymodule"
```

again built and load the image, it is not available in /lib/modules/ directory. Where i can find it? or using other 3 methods will be better?

Comment: Improved formatting of the log messages would be helpful. Also, relevant snippets from dmesg output.

Comment: Also, what FPGA are you using? And host? Sorry, just noticed it is an ARM PCIE host so my comments about BIOS are probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Using insmod to install the driver is the right thing to do. It does not seem to be the cause of the problem you are seeing.

When you build the driver, the .ko file will usually be in the source directory where you built it, unless you `make modules_install`.

Getting back to the actual problem:

Looking at the driver source, the message "Could not remap memory" indicates that the driver could not map the PCIE memory region into the kernel address space.

Looks like the base address registers were not configured. On all the machines I use, the BIOS has to configure the base address registers before Linux can use the device.

We program the FPGA, reboot the machine, and then load the driver and use the FPGA. Did you try this? Does your FPGA show up with lspci?

Once the FPGA is programmed, if the PCIE configuration does not change you can tell the kernel to rescan and it will write the base address registers with the same values.

Comment: kernel to rescan:  unfortunately I don't know how to do this. There were 4 methods to append kernel into the Image: MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS

    MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS

    MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS

    MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS       I used the last one but I have problem as mentioned above. When using one of this method if kernel is added then I think configure base address will be done automatically??? Which one should I use??